# Cannot access object property-Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript

any idea why I cannot access the districts property in regions object?

> const regions = [
> {
> region: "Hlavní město Praha",
> districts:
> "Benešov, Beroun, Kladno, Kolín, Kutná Hora, Mělník, Mladá Boleslav, Nymburk, Praha-východ, Praha-západ, Příbram a Rakovník",
> },   ];

```
console.log(regions.filter((r) => r.region === regionState)[0].districts)
```

it throws an error saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'districts')

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import validator from "validator";

const StepOne = ({ nextStep, handleFormData, values }) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [regionState, setRegionState] = useState("");

  const regions = [
    {
      region: "Hlavní město Praha",
      districts:
        "Benešov, Beroun, Kladno, Kolín, Kutná Hora, Mělník, Mladá Boleslav, Nymburk, Praha-východ, Praha-západ, Příbram a Rakovník",
    },
  ];

  const twoCalls = (e) => {
    handleFormData("region");
    setRegionState(e.target.value);

  };
  console.log(regions.filter((r) => r.region === regionState))

  const submitFormData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (
      validator.isEmpty(values.propertyType) ||
      validator.isEmpty(values.region) ||
      validator.isEmpty(values.district)
    ) {
      setError(true);
    } else {
      nextStep();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Card style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
        <Card.Body>
          <Form onSubmit={submitFormData}>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Typ nemovitosti</Form.Label>
              <Form.Select
                style={{ border: error ? "2px solid red" : "" }}
                onChange={handleFormData("propertyType")}
              >
                {" "}
                <option>Vyberte nemovitost</option>
                <option value="Dům">Dům</option>
                <option value="Byt">Byt</option>
                <option value="Pozemek">Pozemek</option>
              </Form.Select>
              {error ? (
                <Form.Text style={{ color: "red" }}>
                  Toto je povinné pole
                </Form.Text>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Kraj</Form.Label>
              <Form.Select
                style={{ border: error ? "2px solid red" : "" }}
                onChange={twoCalls}
              >
                {" "}
                <option>Vyberte kraj</option>
                {regions.map((region) => (
                  <option value={region.region}>{region.region}</option>
                ))}
              </Form.Select>
              {error ? (
                <Form.Text style={{ color: "red" }}>
                  Toto je povinné pole
                </Form.Text>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Okres</Form.Label>
              <Form.Select
                style={{ border: error ? "2px solid red" : "" }}
                onChange={handleFormData("district")}
              >
                {" "}
                <option>Vyberte okres</option>
 
                )
              </Form.Select>
              {error ? (
                <Form.Text style={{ color: "red" }}>
                  Toto je povinné pole
                </Form.Text>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </Form.Group>

            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
              Pokračovat
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StepOne;
```

Comment: The error looks perfectly clear: `regions.filter((r) => r.region === regionState)[0]` is nothing, so calling `.districts` on it is a type error. Do your work in steps: `const filtered = regions.filter((r) => r.region === regionState);`, then log _that_ to see what's in it and whether there's even an element at position zero to work with.

Comment: it does not actually, it logs the array with first object

Comment: @jenlee123: What is the value of `regionState`?  Please update the question to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and indicating why specifically you expect the output to be different.

Comment: @jenlee123 remember to [put that in your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The same as region value, it gets updated through the state from a select input

Comment: Initially, `regionState === ""`, which doesn’t match any array element.

Comment: @jenlee123: (1) Nowhere in the now updated code are you using the line of code originally throwing the error.  (2) In the now updated code the initial value of `regionState` is `""` which doesn't match any `region` value in the array you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the var "regionState" never matches any of the regions provided in "regions". Because it never matches, it filters everything out from the array, and there's no "districts" attribute because there's nothing at index 0.

You should be able to see this by printing the filtered array or the filtered array's length:

```
let filteredArr = regions.filter((r) => r.region === regionState);
console.log(filteredArr.length);
```

Comment: No, it actually matches when I select a value in a select input. My fault that I didnt share the full code immadeately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).