# Populating second select based on first selection react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner with react.js and I am trying to populate options in select input based on previous selection. I am still getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

which probably means that it couldnt been loaded because the first selection hasnt been made yet. I suspect I should use useEffect hook but not sure in what way.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Form, Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import validator from "validator";

const StepOne = ({ nextStep, handleFormData, values }) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [regionState, setRegionState] = useState("Vyberte okres");
  const [filteredRegions, setFilteredRegions] = useState([]);
  const regions = [
    {
      region: "Hlavní město Praha",
      districts:
        "Benešov, Beroun, Kladno, Kolín, Kutná Hora, Mělník, Mladá Boleslav, Nymburk, Praha-východ, Praha-západ, Příbram a Rakovník",
    },
  ];

  const twoCalls = (e) => {
    handleFormData("region");
    setRegionState(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitFormData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (
      validator.isEmpty(values.propertyType) ||
      validator.isEmpty(values.region) ||
      validator.isEmpty(values.district)
    ) {
      setError(true);
    } else {
      nextStep();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Card style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
        <Card.Body>
          <Form onSubmit={submitFormData}>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Typ nemovitosti</Form.Label>
              <Form.Select
                style={{ border: error ? "2px solid red" : "" }}
                onChange={handleFormData("propertyType")}
              >
                {" "}
                <option>Vyberte nemovitost</option>
                <option value="Dům">Dům</option>
                <option value="Byt">Byt</option>
                <option value="Pozemek">Pozemek</option>
              </Form.Select>
              {error ? (
                <Form.Text style={{ color: "red" }}>
                  Toto je povinné pole
                </Form.Text>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Kraj</Form.Label>
              <Form.Select
                style={{ border: error ? "2px solid red" : "" }}
                onChange={twoCalls}
              >
                {" "}
                <option>Vyberte kraj</option>
                {regions.map((region) => (
                  <option value={region.region}>{region.region}</option>
                ))}
              </Form.Select>
              {error ? (
                <Form.Text style={{ color: "red" }}>
                  Toto je povinné pole
                </Form.Text>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Okres</Form.Label>
              <Form.Select
                style={{ border: error ? "2px solid red" : "" }}
                onChange={handleFormData("district")}
              >
                {" "}
                <option>Vyberte okres</option>
                {regions
                  .filter((r) => r.region === regionState)[0]
                  .districts.split(",")
                  .map((district) => {
                    return <option value={district}>{district}</option>;
                  })}
              </Form.Select>
              {error ? (
                <Form.Text style={{ color: "red" }}>
                  Toto je povinné pole
                </Form.Text>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </Form.Group>

            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
              Pokračovat
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StepOne;
```

Comment: What does `values` props looks like? make sure its not undefined and you're passing it correctly.

Comment: also, log/debug what `e` on `twoCalls` is, it might be a value instead of element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot access object property-Cannot read properties of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71564237/cannot-access-object-property-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined)

Comment: It's failing for exactly the same reason as your previous question.  The `regions` array has one element.  The initial value of `regionState` (which in this code is `"Vyberte okres"` *does not match* any element in that array. So, when rendering, this is `undefined`: `regions.filter((r) => r.region === regionState)[0]`  Because you're trying to access the first element of an array after filtering out all of its elements. You then try to read the `districts` property on that `undefined` value, which causes the error. You need to make sure `.filter()` produces results before using those results.

Answer (score 0):

to get a value base on another value you can use useMemo

```
const secondValue = useMemo( () => {
   const nextValue = yourArray.findIndex(value => value === yourFirstValue) + 1
   if(secondValue === 0 || secondValue === yourArray.length - 1) {
       //check if can't find your value or your value is last item in array
       return anythingYouWant
   }
   return yourArray[nextValue]
},[yourFirstValue, yourArray])
```

secondValue will update every time yourFirstValue or yourArray change

Comment: well I cannot use secondValue variable before I set it to something